# C Issue with include guards

Tags: c, header, include, include-guards

I have a header file which has an include guard setup.  I have multiple C files in my project that require this header file for compilation.  When I go to compile however I get an error saying that the function has already been included from another file.  Shouldn't the include guard prevent this from happening?  In theory I believe I should be able to import this file a bunch of times and not have this issue.

```
#ifndef __BST_INCLUDED
#define __BST_INCLUDED__

//bunch of code here

#endif
```

Error:

```
bst.h:22:13: error: conflicting types for ‘pruneBSTNode’
 extern void pruneBSTNode(bst *tree,bstNode *node);
             ^
In file included from vbst.h:5:0,
                 from bstrees.c:7:
```

Comment: Perhaps use `#pragma once`

Comment: Regarding __BST_INCLUDED, fear the double underscore! [Double underscore is reserved for use by the library implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) Bad and really freaky, hard to debug things can happen if you do this and collide with some library identifier, so just don't.

Comment: @user4581301: So is a single underscore at file-scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#ifndef __BST_INCLUDED
#define __BST_INCLUDED__
//bunch of code here
#endif
```

This will not protect anything. For the simple reason that `__BST_INCLUDED__` is not the same as `__BST_INCLUDED`, and `__BST_INCLUDED` never gets defined.

But also:

```
bst.h:22:13: error: conflicting types for ‘pruneBSTNode’
 extern void pruneBSTNode(bst *tree,bstNode *node);
         ^
In file included from vbst.h:5:0,
                 from bstrees.c:7:
```

this error is not telling you that "the function has been included from another file", it's a completely unrelated error. The "included from" part is just telling you how the compiler got to the line displayed after it (which is missing from the question).

Comment: Yes the other file vbst.h includes bst.h.  I didn't catch that the 2 lines were different.  Thanks that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Your include guards are fine. The problem is that you've declared multiple different signatures for the `pruneBSTNode` function. Make sure the header and the .c file agree on the return type and argument types.

Answer (score 0):

```
__BST_INCLUDED
```

is not the same as

```
__BST_INCLUDED__.
```

Besides, when it comes to compiling headers, my recommendation is that you use more common convention for your include guards

```
#ifndef FILE_NAME_HPP
#define FILE_NAME_HPP


#endif
```

But alas, like the others said. Your error isn't coming from there.